# Filter List by Month

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way we can filter by month. So that we can specific month on load event. 
this is my code and demo [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-sdbhyn-datepicker-fjhus6) as your reference. Actually, my actual code in vscode call API for filter. And I don't know how to provide API in stackblitz for demo.

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="text"
         class="form-control"
         [(ngModel)]="value"
         (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)"
         #dp="bsDatepicker"
         bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'MMMM'}" (onShown)="onOpenCalendar($event)" />
  <span class="input-group-addon" >


<div *ngFor="let monthData of resultData">
    <div class="upcoming-container">
      <div class="upcoming-container-title-section color">
        Group Month | {{ monthData.date }}
      </div>
      <div class="upcoming-container-card-section">
        <div  *ngFor="let card of monthData.bug" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 upcoming-container-card-item">
            <app-card [listData]="card"></app-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 let data = new Set(this.products.map(item => this.datePipe.transform(item.date, 'yyyy-MM')));
    Array.from(data).sort().forEach((date) => {
      this.resultData.push({
        date: date,
        bug: this.products.filter(i => this.datePipe.transform(i.date, 'yyyy-MM') === date)
      })
    });
    console.log(this.resultData)
  }

  onOpenCalendar(container) {
    container.monthSelectHandler = (event: any): void => {
      container._store.dispatch(container._actions.select(event.date));
    };     
    console.log(event)  
    container.setViewMode('month');
  }
```

Comment: why do you want to specify month on load when you can ask API to return a result for that particular month? Or you will fetch all results in one go. In that case, you need two result bodies, one for holding backend results and another for view search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getMonth()`method to filter data based on the month.

Try like this:

```
onValueChange(date) {
    var monthData = this.products.filter(
      x => new Date(x.date).getMonth() == date.getMonth()
    );
    this.getDisplayData(monthData);
}

getDisplayData(inputData) {
    this.resultData = [];
    let data = new Set(
      inputData.map(item => this.datePipe.transform(item.date, "yyyy-MM"))
    );
    Array.from(data)
      .sort()
      .forEach(date => {
        this.resultData.push({
          date: date,
          bug: this.products.filter(
            i => this.datePipe.transform(i.date, "yyyy-MM") === date
          )
        });
      });
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-sdbhyn-datepicker-yrb4ta?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: If I call api to filter..Is it method same too?

Comment: The logic will be same. Syntax may be different based on the backend language you are using. For nodeJS, it will be same.

Comment: I using angular 8

Comment: Thats for UI. The API is in not Angular, a different one.

Comment: If you don't mind... Can I ask you I more question? How to handle this error `ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'getMonth' of null`

Comment: Just check for null. if( date) {} and in the filter,   var monthData = this.products.filter(
      x => x.date &&  new Date(x.date).getMonth() == date.getMonth()
    );